# Convert durations in Ruby - hh:mm:ss.sss to milliseconds and vice versa

Tags: ruby, time

I was wondering if there is a built-in method in Ruby that allows me to convert lap times in the format of hh:mm:ss.sss to milliseconds and vice versa.
Since I need to do some calculations with it, I assumed that converting to milliseconds would be the easiest way to do this. Tell me if I am wrong here :)

Comment: Which calculations you need to do? Ruby `DateTime` class is pretty handy for most types of calculations.

Comment: Adding and subtracting in general. In addition to this these times are bound to a certain intensity, for example:
"02:25.700 at 70% intensity".
Based on this time I would need to calculate the theoretical time at 100% intensity.
For the sake of completeness: these times are not bound to a certain date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
a=[1, 1000, 60000, 3600000]*2
ms="01:45:36.180".split(/[:\.]/).map{|time| time.to_i*a.pop}.inject(&:+)
# => 6336180
t = "%02d" % (ms / a[3]).to_s << ":" << 
    "%02d" % (ms % a[3] / a[2]).to_s << ":" << 
    "%02d" % (ms % a[2] / a[1]).to_s << "." << 
    "%03d" % (ms % a[1]).to_s
# => "01:45:36.180"
```

Comment: Took me quite some time to understand it fully, but works like a charm :) Thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry, I ought to put some comments in there instead of code golfing.

Answer (score 3):

As you are ignoring the date altogether, and possibly have numbers greater than 24 as number of hours, maybe existing Ruby classes aren't suitable for you (at least ones from the standard lib).

Actually, there are couple of methods which might be helpful: [time_to_day_fraction](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/time_to_day_fraction/class) and [day_fraction_to_time](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/day_fraction_to_time/class), but for some reason they are private (at least in 1.9.1).

So you can either monkey-patch them to make them public, or simply copy-paste their implementation to your code:

```
def time_to_day_fraction(h, min, s)
  Rational(h * 3600 + min * 60 + s, 86400) # 4p
end

def day_fraction_to_time(fr)
  ss,  fr = fr.divmod(Rational(1, 86400)) # 4p
  h,   ss = ss.divmod(3600)
  min, s  = ss.divmod(60)
  return h, min, s, fr
end
```

They are working with `Rational` class, so you can calculate easily with them.

Comment: If I add the milliseconds, this should work. Will try that out later. Thanks :)

Comment: It already works with the milliseconds, you just pass seconds as Float or Rational (`time_to_day_fraction(1,45,22.345)`).

Comment: You're right, sorry, I tried only in ruby 1.9.1 and assumed it would work in previous versions as well. Well, you could either use Rational, add milliseconds parameter to the methods, or use Jonas' methods. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Convert seconds into HH:MM:SS in Ruby](https://gist.github.com/shunchu/3175001)

```
t = 323 # seconds
Time.at(t).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
=> "00:03:56"
```