# What is the proper way to form Rails data before I store it in my Postgres interval data-type column?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, undefined, intervals

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with a Postgres database.  In my database, I have a column “time_in_ms” of type, “interval”.  From my Rails form, I want to save my hours, minutes, and seconds drop downs into this single column, and then also displays the values accurately when they are pulled from the database.  What is the proper way to do this?  Right now, in my Rails model, I save milliseconds into my “time_in_ms” column.  So if this is the value

```
60000000
```

I see this in my Postgres database …

```
16666:40:00
```

Whatever that means.  Then when I try and display the values from the database, I get these errors:

```
undefined method `/' for "16666:40:00":String
```

complaining about this line …

```
<td><%= (my_object_time.time_in_ms/(1000*60*60))%24 %>:<%= ((my_object_time.time_in_ms/(1000*60))%60).to_s.rjust(2,'0') %>:<%= ((my_object_time.time_in_ms/1000)%60).to_s.rjust(2,'0') %></td>
```

How should I formulate my data before it is saved into Postgres and how should I then properly display it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in using the `interval` type for saving hours, minutes and seconds. *But* this will not save the milliseconds.

What you did was converting a time into milliseconds. Your interval field only knows of seconds, and `6_000_000` seconds resulted in `16666:40:0` - exceeding the `1_000_000` seconds it represents, which seems to be the max limit.

You should approach this differently:

Use the `interval` field as intended: save *hours*, *minutes*, and *seconds* into a column - they are part of your form anyway. Then it will be easy to display it in the view as well.

Then, if you want to retrieve your milliseconds, simply add a method:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  def time_in_milliseconds
    # retrieve the interval seconds from the database and multiply by 1000
  end
end
```

Also, for handling the conversion of milliseconds to `hh:mm:ss` format and back you should check out [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379624/2235594).

Comment: Additionally, you're putting a large amount of logic in the view, which is considered bad practice. Try, if possible to not use math in your view and keep it down to if else statements and loops. You could turn this into a helper method if you intend to use this in many different areas in the project. Otherwise, you should probably process the output in the model. Hope this helps! :)